Can someone help me solve this eigenvalue problem?
I need to find the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and corresponding eigenfunctions $h_n(\tau)$ that satisfy the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{r^2} e^{-2i\tau} \left(i \frac{dh}{d\tau} - \frac{d^2 h}{d\tau^2}\right) + \lambda^2 h(\tau) = 0,
\end{equation}
where:

$\tau$ is an angular coordinate in the interval $(0, 2\pi]$,
$r$ is a strictly positive real constant,
$\lambda^2$ represents the eigenvalues associated with the problem, I am looking for an infinite set of discrete eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenfunctions.
$h(\tau)$ is a complex-valued eigenfunction of $\tau$.
$i=\sqrt{-1}$

The problem is subject to periodic boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
h(0) = h(2\pi) = c_1, \quad \frac{dh}{d\tau}\Big|_{\tau=0} = \frac{dh}{d\tau}\Big|_{\tau=2\pi} = c_2,
\end{equation}
where:

$c_1$ and $c_2$ are given non-negative constants (can be zero).

I have tried several ansatzes including $h(\tau)=exp(in\tau) u(\tau)$ with $u$ representing some periodic function satisfying the same boundary conditions, but did not have any luck with it. Any support and help will be highly appreciated.
I tried Strum-Liouville theory, which sounds like the first appropriate method, but I still had no luck with it. I am not saying you should not try these; I am just giving you a heads-up about the non-trivial nature of the problem.

Isn't this, with four boundary conditions, overdetermined?

Titles should quickly give a reader what kind of,problem it is. "Can anybody help me.." doesn't, because everybody asking a question here is essentially asking if anybody can help them. On the other hand, nothing in the title said differential equation - there are eigenvalue problems in elementary linear algebra as well. Help people help you.

Have you tried fourier series?

Did you mean Sturm–Liouville theory?

Let $\alpha(\tau):=\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ for some function $\tau\mapsto t(\tau)$ to be determined below. Then by the Leibniz/chain rule (with $\tilde{h}(t):=h(\tau(t))$):
\begin{align*}
\frac{dh}{d\tau}&=\alpha(\tau)\frac{d\tilde{h}}{dt},\\
\frac{d^2h}{d\tau^2}&=\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\alpha(\tau)\frac{d\tilde{h}}{dt}\right)=\alpha'(\tau)\frac{d\tilde{h}}{dt}+\alpha(\tau)^2\frac{d^2\tilde{h}}{dt^2}.
\end{align*}
In order to cancel the first order derivative, we impose $\alpha'=i\alpha$, that is we put:
\begin{align*}
\alpha(\tau)&=e^{i\tau},\\
t(\tau)&=-ie^{i\tau}=e^{i(\tau-\pi/2)}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the equation transforms as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-2i\tau}\left(i\frac{dh}{d\tau}-\frac{d^2h}{d\tau^2}\right)+\lambda^2h(\tau)&=\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-2i\tau}\left(i\alpha(\tau)\frac{d\tilde{h}}{dt}-\alpha'(\tau)\frac{d\tilde{h}}{dt}-\alpha(\tau)^2\frac{d^2\tilde{h}}{dt^2}\right)+\lambda^2\tilde{h}(t)\\
%
&=-\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-2i\tau}\alpha(\tau)^2\frac{d^2\tilde{h}}{dt^2}+\lambda^2\tilde{h}(t)\\
%
&=-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d^2\tilde{h}}{dt^2}+\lambda^2\tilde{h}(t).
\end{align*}
This is a second order, linear, ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients which can be easily handled.
Note that, since $\tau\in(0,2\pi]$, $t\mapsto\tau(t)$ is well defined.

The author asked me to finish the computations.
To be rigorous when dealing with (partial) differential equations, we have to specify a functional space to work in (this has tremendous consequences such as selecting some solutions while removing some others). Here, since we work with the elliptic operator $-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ on the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$, so that eigenfunctions are necessarily smooth in $\mathbb{S}^1$.
For the sake of definiteness, I will assume that henceforth $\lambda\neq0$. The standard theory of linear ordinary differential equations entails that the solutions $\tilde{h}$ are of the form
$$\tilde{h}(t)=C_-e^{-r\lambda t}+C_+e^{r\lambda t}$$
for some constants $C_-,C_+\in\mathbb{C}$. Back to the variable $\tau\in(0,2\pi]$, we obtain:
$$h(\tau)=C_-e^{ir\lambda e^{i\tau}}+C_+e^{-ir\lambda e^{i\tau}}.$$
Now we use the boundary conditions:
\begin{align*}
c_1&=h(0)=h(2\pi)=C_-e^{ir\lambda}+C_+e^{-ir\lambda},\\
%
c_2&=h'(0)=h'(2\pi)=-r\lambda C_-e^{ir\lambda}+r\lambda C_+e^{-ir\lambda}.
\end{align*}
Solving for $C_-,C_+$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}C_-\\C_+\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}e^{ir\lambda}&e^{-ir\lambda}\\-e^{ir\lambda}&e^{-ir\lambda}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\\frac{c_2}{r\lambda}\end{pmatrix}\\
%
&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}e^{-ir\lambda}&-e^{-ir\lambda}\\e^{ir\lambda}&e^{ir\lambda}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\\frac{c_2}{r\lambda}\end{pmatrix}\\
%
&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}(c_1-\frac{c_2}{r\lambda})e^{-ir\lambda}\\(c_1+\frac{c_2}{r\lambda})e^{ir\lambda}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
It comes:
$$h(\tau)=\frac{(c_1-\frac{c_2}{r\lambda})e^{ir\lambda(e^{i\tau}-1)}}{2}+\frac{(c_1+\frac{c_2}{r\lambda})e^{ir\lambda(1-e^{i\tau})}}{2}.$$
In this case, the boundary conditions do not yield any quantization of the eingenvalues $\lambda$, as it would for example for the equation $-\frac{d^2h}{d\tau^2}+\lambda^2u=0$, $\tau\in[0,1]$, with boundary conditions $h(0)=h(1)=0$: in this case, the eignvalues are of the form $\lambda=2\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks for answering Nicolas,
This is certainly helpful for finding the general and particular solutions of the problem with the prescribed data.
Do you have any suggestions if say I am interested in finding the spectral solutions for the associated operator, namely this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{r^2} e^{-2i\tau} \left(i \frac{d}{d\tau} - \frac{d^2 }{d\tau^2}\right)
\end{equation}
Like a series of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues.
Any further help will be highly appreciated.

@Wakil Hasn't my answer given you the solution? Do you need me to carry out the remaining computations to get $\tau\mapsto h(\tau)$?

yes, please if you could, that will be superb.
